# XeLaTeX: mathtools, unicode-math and \text spoil \mathtt

Tags: xetex, miktex, unicode-math, mathtools

I work on a big XeLaTeX document and encountered a rendering bug(?) with my MiKTeX installation (all packages are updated as per April 10, 2016). Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\DeclareSymbolFont{somemeaninglessname}{\encodingdefault}{\familydefault}{m}{it}

\begin{document}
    \[ \mathtt{z} \]
    \[ \text{$z$} \]
    \[ \mathtt{z} \]
\end{document}
```

I'd expect first and third line to be the same. However, it's not the case:

[image: MiKTeX rendering result]

I asked my friend to render same file on Linux with TeXLive-2014, and here is what he got:

[image: TeXLive rendering result]

However, if I move `\usepackage{mathtools}` right after `\DeclareSymbolFont`'s line, everything works on my system as expected:

[image: Fixed MiKTeX render]

Moving it in between `\usepackage{unicode-math}` and `\DeclareSymbolFont` does nothing.

I'm not sure whether it's a bug or incorrect usage of either package. Unfortunately, I do not really understand what `\DeclareSymbolFont` does - it was written by another person. What is going on here?

*UPD*: looks like [it's not MiKTeX-specific](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303538/miktex-xelatex-mathtools-unicode-math-and-text-spoil-mathtt#comment735839_303538) problem and happens on TeXLie 15 as well.

Comment: `\usepackage{unicode-math}` should go after all other math packages, as recommended in it's documentation.

Comment: It is not a problem specific to miktex. I see it with texlive 15 too. The problem is that when mathtools is detected unicode-math issues a `\newfam \g__um_empty_fam` and disturbs the family detection, but I can't look deeper now.

Comment: imho it is a bug https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/345

Answer (score 1):

This problem arose again here: [Incompatibility with mathtools and unicode-math in xelatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/335164/incompatibility-with-mathtools-and-unicode-math-in-xelatex), and a patch is to be found in [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/335177/4686).

A [pull request](https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/pull/369) has been made on the unicode-math developer site, to fix the issue which had been [reported there](https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/345) by @UlrikeFischer.

Answer (score 0):

It does not happen with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareSymbolFont{somemeaninglessname}{\encodingdefault}{\familydefault}{m}{it}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
[...]
```