# Vanishing math font styles in unicode-math due to a mess of mathtools, mathtt and using math fonts with ranges

Tags: xetex, luatex, unicode-math, mathtools

I’m using TeXLive 2015.

Okay, so I have some sort of poltergeist in the following code.
I compile it with either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{
    fontspec,
%   mathtools,
    unicode-math,
}

\setmathfont[
%   range = \mathcal,
]{xits-math.otf}

\begin{document}

%   $\mathtt L$
    $\mathcal L$

\end{document}
```

The desired output – when uncommenting all lines – should be:

[image: desired output]

However, when uncommenting all lines and compiling with `xelatex` the script ‘L’ is missing.
I found out that (re-)commenting out *any* of the three lines `mathtools,` `range = \mathcal` and `$\mathtt L$` will restore the script ‘L’.
Unfortunately, I have a scenario in which I need all three lines.

Also, compiling with `lualatex` doesn’t seem to yield any problems.

A similar question is [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303538/xelatex-mathtools-unicode-math-and-text-spoil-mathtt), where [this bug report](https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/345) for the `unicode-math` package has come up. Is that stemming from the same issue or is there something else going on here?

Comment: Curiously enough, if you add `\setmathfont[range=\mathscr]{xits-math.otf}`, the script glyph reappears.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a misfeature, but a workaround is to load again the main math font for the `\mathscr` range; you also have to declare anew the main math font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{
    fontspec,
    unicode-math,
}

\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}[
  range = \mathcal,
]
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[
  range = \mathscr
]

\begin{document}

$A$
$\symtt{L}$
$\mathcal{L}$

\end{document}
```

Note that the correct call for a typewriter type variable is `\symtt`, or `\mathtt` would load the text monospaced font.

[image]

This is the `pdffonts` report:

```
BRCTEL+LatinModernMath-Regular-Identity-H CID Type 0C       yes yes yes      5  0
HSKWQU+XITSMath-Identity-H           CID Type 0C       yes yes yes      7  0
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround! Actually, I want the text monospaced font to load (that is to *match* the text monospace font). Is there any reason why one wants to use `\symtt` instead? If the letters were used for mathematics only or something? (What font will be loaded with `\symtt`?)

Comment: @k.stm I suspected your preference for the monospaced document font. With `\symtt` you choose the “monospaced math letters” in the designated Unicode math font.

Answer (score 1):

This is the same issue which was mentioned in [XeLaTeX: mathtools, unicode-math and \text spoil \mathtt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303538/xelatex-mathtools-unicode-math-and-text-spoil-mathtt) and again more recently in [Incompatibility with mathtools and unicode-math in xelatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/335164/incompatibility-with-mathtools-and-unicode-math-in-xelatex).

There is a patch proposed in my answer to the more recent question.

And yes, the [bug report](https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/345) you cite is about this issue. A [pull request](https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/pull/369) has been made to incorporate the fix into unicode-math.