# Why does my \mathcal character disappear?

Tags: unicode-math

My MWE

```
\documentclass[varwidth, border=0.2in]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[]{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\setmathfont[range={cal}]{Latin Modern Math}
\begin{document}
  The distribution of $\mathbf{X}$ is $\mathcal{P}\{\mathbf{X} = k\}$.
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

Note the absence of the `\mathcal{P}` character. Confusingly, if I comment out `\usepackage{mathtools}`, it appears to work:

[image]

**EDIT:**
I took the advice from the duplicate bug — it works, but only partly. Now I'm losing `\mathscr` characters, although I have the `\mathcal` characters back:

```
\documentclass[varwidth, border=0.2in]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\setmathfont[range={cal}]{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[range={scr}]{TeX Gyre Pagella Math} %% Added this line
\begin{document}
  The distribution of $\mathbf{X}$ is $\mathcal{P}\{\mathbf{X} = k\}$,
  in the collection $\mathscr{P}$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

I've tried setting the math fonts in many different ways, but one of the two alphabets is always disappearing.

**EDIT:**
The closest I've come to a workaround is to load `amsmath`, then `unicode-math`, then `mathtools`. (Yes, I understand this is counter the documentation of `unicode-math`.) That works in that I'm able to see all my characters. Unfortunately, changing the font with `\small`, for example, changes all boldface math characters to non-boldface. Not ideal.

Answer (score 2):

This link may help you: 
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/315137/115042

In order to solve the problem you have to load the math font again. I think it's some kind of overload between the packages.

```
\documentclass[varwidth, border=0.2in]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}[
  range = \mathcal,
]
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[
  range = \mathscr
]
\begin{document}
  The distribution of $\mathbf{X}$ is $\mathcal{P} \{\mathbf{X} = k\}$.
\end{document}
```

Using the code above I get the follow result:

[image]

Comment: So what about getting the original `\mathcal{P}`, not the script-like one `\mathscr{P}`?

Comment: This script-like look in the above is, I think, correct — at least, it matches the appearance of \mathcal{P} in XITS when I run a standalone test.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is a good option for you, but if you are only using `\mathbf` in a limited way e.g. for vectors, etc., then setting `mathbf=sym` might be a reasonable workaround.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[mathbf=sym]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[range={cal}]
\begin{document}
  The distribution of $\mathbf{X}$ is $\mathcal{P}\{\mathbf{X} = k\}$, in the collection $\mathscr{P}$.
\end{document}
```

[image: <code>mathbf=sym</code>]

Answer (score 0):

This is again the same issue which arose in [XeLaTeX: mathtools, unicode-math and \text spoil \mathtt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303538/xelatex-mathtools-unicode-math-and-text-spoil-mathtt), [Vanishing math font styles in unicode-math due to a mess of mathtools, mathtt and using math fonts with ranges](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315006/vanishing-math-font-styles-in-unicode-math-due-to-a-mess-of-mathtools-mathtt-an), and more recently [Incompatibility with mathtools and unicode-math in xelatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/335164/incompatibility-with-mathtools-and-unicode-math-in-xelatex).

See [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/335177/4686) for a proposed patch.