# Incompatibility with mathtools and unicode-math in xelatex?

Tags: xetex, incompatibility, unicode-math, mathtools, bugs

I find unexpected behaviour in using mathtools in conjunction with unicode-math, which shows up if the 'range' command is used. Some incompatibilities have been noted before, so perhaps this is related. However, it only showed up for me in Texlive2016; previous versions worked as expected. In the following example I wish to draw calligraphic fonts from a different set than the main maths fonts, and some calligraphic symbols, and a regular italic bold face math, are missing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\unimathsetup{math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO,sans-style=italic}
\setmainfont{xits-regular.otf}
\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}
\setmathfont[range={\mathcal,\mathbfcal}]{latinmodern-math.otf}
%\setmathfont[range={}]{xits-math.otf} % Try with and without this line
%
\begin{document}
Test
$a+b = \mathcal{C H G}C \mathscr{D}$
$$-\frac{a}{b} \mathcal{O} . $$
\begin{equation}
    \mathrm{d} = \mathcal G(\varphi,x,y,z,t) , 
\end{equation}
The symbol $\mathcal{G}$ is missing.

The following equation is wrong if I include the line  ``setmathfont[range=\{\}] \{xits-math.otf\}''
\begin{equation}
    \mathup{d} = \symbf{u}(\varphi,x,y,z,t) , 
\end{equation}
The glyph $\symbf{u}$ is missing.
\end{document}
```

If mmathtools is called after unicode-math the problem does not arise, but this ordering is not recommend by the unicode-math developers.

My specific question is, is this a bug or is it something I am doing wrong?

Comment: The glyph should be there if you use `\symbf` instead of `\mathbf`. The real problem when you add the line with the empty range is that the previous range declaration is lost.

Comment: @egreg GeoffV does not seem to be using `\mathbf`, which `\mathbf` are you referring to  ?

Comment: @jfbu Apparently they have been changed. I copied the original version.

Comment: @GeoffV updated answer to fix the unicode-math issue with `\newfam`. Will make a PR on the developer's site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### update:

The [github issue](https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/345) related to this and opened by @UlrikeFischer was closed some time ago already at unicode-math `v0.8e`, and currently unicode-math is at `v0.8m`. So don't use the hack below.

---

---

Update. Here is an attempt at addressing the `\newfam` issue. We temporarily make innocent `\newfam` during `unicode-math` loading (I checked it was used only once; as it is used during patching of `mathtools`, `mathtools` must be loaded before `unicode-math`). Then we patch ourselves the mathtools macro. For this, I use the math family number 255 rather than creating a new one. It is not very probable the document uses 256 math families. One could make this more intrinsic by using `\e@mathgroup@top - 1` but I don't know how to subtract 1 in expl3 lingua. Caveat: barely tested.

This addresses only one the two issues. The one of effect of empty range is not handled here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

% *must* be before unicode-math
\usepackage{mathtools} 

\makeatletter
\let\ORInewfam\newfam
\def\newfam #1{\typeout{message from \string\newfam: killing myself}}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\let\newfam\ORInewfam
\makeatother


\unimathsetup{math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO,sans-style=italic}
\setmainfont{xits-regular.otf}
\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}
\setmathfont[range={\mathcal,\mathbfcal}]{latinmodern-math.otf}
%\setmathfont[range={}]{xits-math.otf} % Try with and without this line

\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\def\MT_cramped_internal:Nn #1#2
     {
      \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box
       {
        \color@setgroup
        \c_math_toggle_token
        \m@th
        #1
        \dim_zero:N \nulldelimiterspace
        \XeTeXradical \c_two_hundred_fifty_five \c_zero { #2 }
        \c_math_toggle_token
        \color@endgroup
       }
      \box_set_ht:Nn \l_tmpa_box
       {
        \box_ht:N \l_tmpa_box
        - \__um_radical_vgap:N #1
       }
      \box_use_drop:N \l_tmpa_box
     }
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Test
$a+b = \mathcal{C H G}C \mathscr{D}$
$$-\frac{a}{b} \mathcal{O} . $$
\begin{equation}
    \mathrm{d} = \mathcal{G}(\varphi,x,y,z,t) , 
\end{equation}
% The symbol $\mathcal{G}$ is NOT missing.

% The following equation is wrong if I include the line  ``setmathfont[range=\{\}] \{xits-math.otf\}''
\begin{equation}
    \mathup{d} = \symbf{u}(\varphi,x,y,z,t) , 
\end{equation}
% The glyph $\symbf{u}$ is NOT missing.

Example from mathtools manual

\[
\cramped{x^2} \leftrightarrow x^2 \quad
\cramped[\scriptstyle]{x^2} \leftrightarrow {\scriptstyle x^2}
\]

\end{document}
```

<sub>code updated 2018/12/28 as per @egreg comment "`\box_use_clear:N` is deprecated as of 2018-12-31; the right function to use is `\box_use_drop:N`"</sub>

[image]

> <strike>please don't upvote this until it has received confirmation by competent people. It is true that removing some code from unicode-math-xetex.sty makes the thing work, but it may well be that OP's code is not correct use of unicode-math: as I am not familiar with it I can't judge.</strike>
>
> please start upvoting this answer massively as I have grown competent enough to be certain of the origin of the problem (see bottom)
>
> ok, you may stop upvoting and **start transferring your votes to Ulrike's answer** as she had already opened quite some time ago the ticket https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/345 mentioning the pertubation caused by naked use of `\newfam` on math alphabets and thus finding in anticipation which code line in unicode-math ultimately resulted in the disappearing glyphs as here in the OP's question.

### Part I

I have identified the source of the problem in file `unicode-math-xetex.sty`.

Steps to reproduce:

```
kpsewhich unicode-math-xetex.sty
copy the file to your working repertory
comment out lines #L2040 to #L2091 inclusive
```

Then your document compiles fine with the expected glyphs with both mathtools and your  `\setmathfont[range={}]{xits-math.otf}`

Note: the code of unicode-math looks strange with the `\AtEndOfPackageFile * { mathtools }` nested into another one... but I checked balancing of braces. Thus, lines 2038 and 2039 must remain non-commented.

It could be that the important thing in the commented out code is that it does  `\newfam \g__um_empty_fam` creating a new `\mathgroup`. This may cause a problem of numbering ?

Not being familiar with unicode-math I can't comment more. But it does look more like a problem in `unicode-math` than one in `mathtools` (as far as I can tell.)

extra info: I have checked that `\mv@normal` has exact same meaning in the two situations, confirming that there may be an offset in numbering of math families on the `unicode-math` side.

image showing it does work: (the math calligraphic are from XITS not Latin Modern, due to effect of `range={}`)

[image]

### Part II

Here is a minimal example to demonstrate the bug lies in `unicode-math` (see the various comments below this answer for more context).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\newfam\MyFam  % comment this to get correct glyph rather than invisible one

\setmainfont{lmroman10-regular.otf}
\setmathfont[range={cal}]{latinmodern-math.otf}

\begin{document}

$\mathrm{d} = \mathcal{G}$

\showoutput
\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% TeX-engine: xetex
%%% End:
```

The use of `\newfam` before `\setmainfont/\setmathfont` (the latter using the `cal` not the deprecated `range={\mathcal}`) is enough to create the problem: [image]. Without the `\newfam` we get [image].

In case some doubt arises because Latin Modern is default use

```
\setmathfont[range={cal}]{texgyretermes-math.otf}
```

I have opened a ticket at https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/368.

And the point is that the **single** (direct) use of `\newfam` in unicode-math  code is in the line

```
    \newfam \g__um_empty_fam
```

which is encountered at the start of its patch of `mathtools` which in **Part I** I advised to comment out. If this patch is executed too soon in the preamble a problem arises in using `\math..` alphabet macros: the wrong font is used. <strike>This may have to do with `unicode-math` way of patching `\use@mathgroup` but</strike> I have not pursued further because the LaTeX code for math fonts is very complex and whenever I stay a few months without looking at it I forget it entirely and irrevocably, and it would take me quite some effort to re-immerse me into it, not to mention that I would need to read `unicode-math` code as well.

Comment: kudos on the warning.  i'm not upvoting, as warned, since i'm not sufficiently competent, but it does sound like you've uncovered some very useful and relevant information.

Comment: I confirm what I wrote in my comment to the question. There is no missing symbol, but the calligraphic letters revert to the XITS ones. I get exactly the same output with or without the lines you tell to remove.

Comment: @egreg Yes, the calligraphic letters do revert to the XITS ones due to effect as you said of `\setmathfont[range={}]{xits-math.otf}`, and the image above shows them. I don't understand why you get the same output. If I don't remove the lines I get different output where both the calligraphic G and the bold u are missing and replaced by open squares.

Comment: due to a moment of confusion I suppressed a comment here which was confirming my sayings, to be brief it is all as in my answer. Only if I patch unicode-math I get correct output with or without the `range={}` (in case it is used the calligraphic revert to XITS as in my image). Else: `Missing character: There is no  in font [xits-regular]/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;!`

Comment: @jfbu OK, now I see it again. I had changed `\mathrm` to `\symrm` and `\mathup` to `\symup`. Try it yourself. There's definitely something hairy going on and perhaps your idea of a wrongly assigned math group is good.

Comment: On the other hand, if I delay the loading of `mathtools` (loading first `amsmath` alone) the output is correct (apart from the calligraphic letter problem).

Comment: @egreg  I need to move loading of `mathtools` at very end of preamble. I tested mwe `$\mathrm{d} = \mathcal{G}$\showoutput` (without range={} thing). Delayed loading of `mathtools` lead to `\sym__um_fam1=\mathgroup4` and `\g__um_empty_fam=\mathgroup5` in this order. And `\EU1/latinmodern-math.otf(0)/m/n/10 glyph#3558` in box, but with earlier loading of `mathtools` `\EU1/xits-regular.otf(1)/m/n/10 glyph#0`. No such mix-up of mathgroups if `\symrm{d}` is used indeed. If I have now leave `mathtools` first, and rather than commenting out (see next comment)...

Comment: @egreg ... the bad lines, I replace (the two) `\AtEndOfPackage * {mathtools}` by (a single) `\AtBeginDocument` and I comment out the 4 lines with `\eqcolon` etc... to avoid already defined warnings, then the code compiles fine again. This demonstrates that the problems is in unicode-math if its mathtools patch is executed before the `\setmainfont/\setmathsfont` or possibly `\unimathsetup`. This bug shows only if some `\math..` command is used. If the patch is delayed enough, there is no problem. If it is executed too soon, there is a problem.

Comment: Thanks to @jfbu for the work. I've upvoted but will wait a while longer before accepting the answer as it seems a tricky issue

Comment: I knew I had seen it already ... https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/345

Comment: @UlrikeFischer excellent thanks, I will close my ticket as it is a duplicate !

Comment: @UlrikeFischer +1 for #345 showing it without even unicode-math ! I actually also wanted at some point to explore the `\newfam` issue without unicode-math but had spent already enough time on this ;-)

Comment: So, to summarise, it appears that the bug has already been identified and reported on github, so the developers presumably know about it, although a fix does not appear to be imminent.  If this is all so, I should accept the answer and we should all move on - right?

Comment: @GeoffV yes, I think that's pretty much it. I will think a bit if I see an easy patch, but this might require plunging into LaTeX code about math mode which is not simple.

Comment: I found a related bug. Not sure it is the same or not, so I have opened a new question at 
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/336243/another-glitch-with-unicode-math-range-and-xelatex

Answer (score 3):

I don't quite understand why you are using an empty range, but imho your syntax is wrong. You are still using in many place `\mathXX` commands where `\symXX` should be used, and in the range command you should use the names for the blocks and not commands. This here works fine for me on texlive 2016:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\unimathsetup{math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO,sans-style=italic}
\setmainfont{xits-regular.otf}
\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}
\setmathfont[range={cal,bfcal}]{latinmodern-math.otf}
\setmathfont[range={}]{xits-math.otf} % Try with and without this line
%
\begin{document}
Test
$a+b = \symcal{C H G}C \symscr{D}$
$$-\frac{a}{b} \symcal{O} . $$
\begin{equation}
    \symrm{d} = \symcal G(\varphi,x,y,z,t) ,
\end{equation}
The symbol $\symcal{G}$ is missing.

The following equation is wrong if I include the line  ``setmathfont[range=\{\}] \{xits-math.otf\}''
\begin{equation}
    \symup{d} = \symbf{u}(\varphi,x,y,z,t) ,
\end{equation}
The glyph $\symbf{u}$ is missing.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: True that it should be `\symrm`, but `\mathrm` is allowed anyway (for different purposes). Since using `\mathrm` causes the disparition of the symbols, it's clear that there is a problem. Second issue: a further `range` declaration cancels the previous one.

Comment: @egreg: Somehow my comment from yesterday night got lost: You are naturally right, that \mathrm is allowed but imho unicode-math is complicated enough so one should at least start with correct documents when investigating ... (I will try to look into the range problem)

Comment: @egreg: In part (regarding symbols) \newfam ("which one shouldn't use") is responsable for the range problem too, but the main problem is your old bug report:https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/331

Comment: With the latest unicode-math and mathtools packages I no longer see the errant behaviour.  If indeed the the bug is fixed perhaps the question should be closed?

Comment: What version are you using that avoids the errors?

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply. I now use: 
TeXLive 2017, 
Mathtools 2018/01/08 v1.21
Fontspec: {2017/11/09}{2.6g}
unicode-math:  {2018/01/13} {v0.8k}

The file now typesets as expected.