# Another glitch with unicode-math, range, and xelatex

Tags: math-mode, fonts, xetex, unicode-math

When typesetting the following MWE with xelatex I obtain an unexpected symbol, an empty square, between the two lines in the equation. It typesets fine in lualatex. The unexpected symbol shows up when using a different font for the text in math mode than for the other symbols, which is a fairly common thing to do. Similar problems have been reported before, such as here:
   [Incompatibility with mathtools and unicode-math in xelatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/335164/incompatibility-with-mathtools-and-unicode-math-in-xelatex)

However, the new example does not involved mathtools in any way.

The problem only shows up with certain font sets, as indicated in the MWE, below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}
\setmathfont[range=up/{latin,Latin,num}]{XCharter-Roman.otf} % extra character appears between two lines
%\setmathfont[range=up/{latin,Latin,num}]{Charis SIL}  % extra character appears between two lines
%\setmathfont[range=up/{latin,Latin,num}]{texgyretermes-regular.otf}  % works okay with this
%\setmathfont[range=up/{latin,Latin,num}]{Times}  % works okay with this
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*} 
  x = \begin{cases}
  y \\  y   
    \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

And here is the output[image]

Unless I am doing something wrong (always the most likely thing), I guess this is a bug, but I am not sure where - unicode-math, xelatex, the opentype font itself? Is it the same bug as has been reported before?

Comment: It's a known problem: https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/351

Comment: Pretty serious one, then. It means you can't use different text and math fonts, and use the text font for things like sin, cos, log etc, without the risk of some failure.

Comment: The bug seems to have been solved with `unicode-math` version 0.8j, released 2018-01-07.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is no longer relevant as the bug has been fixed.

Comment: I guess you saying that a question that is on-topic when posted, because it points to a bug or similar, becomes off-topic when the bug is fixed. Okay.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the reasons for closing are just a few to choose from. Closing this question doesn't mean it wasn't relevant at the time it was posed. The comment I left should explain it.