# Incompatibility with mathtools and unicode-math in lualatex - \MT_cramped_internal:Nn?

Tags: luatex, unicode-math, mathtools

In my MNWE example shown below:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
  \usepackage{mathtools}  
  \usepackage{unicode-math} 
% \usepackage{lualatex-math} 

\begin{document}
Foo.
\end{document}
```

**Note:** I found the similar question [Incompatibility with mathtools and unicode-math in xelatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/335164/incompatibility-with-mathtools-and-unicode-math-in-xelatex/335177#335177), but it is 4 years old topic, and also I don't understand it.

---

**Lualatex compiler output:**

```
("C:/Users/z0037rdx/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/lualatex/lualatex-mat
h/lualatex-math.sty"
**Package: lualatex-math 2020/09/25 v1.9** Patches for mathematics typesetting with
 LuaLaTeX
("C:/Users/z0037rdx/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolb
ox.sty"
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count279
)
Lua module: lualatex-math 2013/08/03 1.3 Patches for mathematics typesetting wit
h LuaLaTeX

Package lualatex-math Warning: I've expected \MT_cramped_internal:Nn to have
(lualatex-math)                the meaning
(lualatex-math)                macro:#1#2->\sbox \z@ {$\m@th
(lualatex-math)                #1\nulldelimiterspace =\z@ \radical \z@
(lualatex-math)                {#2}$}\ifx #1\displaystyle \dimen@ =\fontdimen
(lualatex-math)                8\textfont 3\advance \dimen@ .25\fontdimen
(lualatex-math)                5\textfont 2\else \dimen@ =1.25\fontdimen 8\ifx
(lualatex-math)                #1\textstyle \textfont \else \ifx
(lualatex-math)                #1\scriptstyle \scriptfont \else
(lualatex-math)                \scriptscriptfont \fi \fi 3\fi \advance \dimen@
(lualatex-math)                -\ht \z@ \ht \z@ =-\dimen@ \box \z@ ,
(lualatex-math)                but it has the meaning
(lualatex-math)                macro:#1#2->{\ensuremath {\use:c
(lualatex-math)                {cramped\cs_to_str:N #1}#2}}.
```

Comment: you can ignore the warning. lualatex-math only tells you that it doesn't patch a mathtools definition as it has changed. hopefully lualatex-math will be updated soon and remove the warning.

Comment: Btw why is it listing version 1.3 of lualatex-math? Exactly what latex system are you on? The current version on ctan is v1. 9 from 2020

Comment: @Daleif. It is strange for me. I normally rely on update function of the Miktex Console Window. The program reports that everything is updated. How this should be done properly? The more I work with latex, the more I become a frustrated programmer.

Comment: I never use miktex as I find the update process confusing. Did you update miktex as both miktex user mode and miktex admin mode? Things installed by the former takes precedent even if a newer version is installed on the latter. I tend to use texlive where we don't have this difference.

Comment: No looking further on the log, you seem to have the latest. I was relating to `Lua module: lualatex-math 2013/08/03 1.3 Patches for mathematics typesetting wit h LuaLaTeX` that version number seems something different from the latex package version. Sorry for the confusion