# mathtools + XeTeX + unicode-math + beamer makes upright math have unexpected behavior

Tags: beamer, unicode-math, incompatibility, mathtools

Problem: In the below MWE, math is rendered correctly, unless there is `\mathrm` or an operator like `\sin`, and then the entire `$...$` is rendered in upright font; Further, all future `$...$` are upright.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}    
\setmainfont{XITS}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}


\begin{document}

$this is italic$ 
$$italic$$
$this is already upright. \sin x$ $now upright$
$$ upright?$$
\[ why is it?\]

\end{document}
```

I guess there's a lot of packages for a MWE, but I think this is the smallest I can make it:

- Replacing `\documentclass{beamer}`, `\usefonttheme{serif}` with `\documentclass{article}` makes it work normally (but I'm trying to make slides)
- similarly with removing either `mathtools`, or `unicode-math` and the font settings.

I tried reordering the packages, I don't think that did anything. Same thing happens (and was discovered) in a `frame` environment. I'm on TeX Live 2017, Macbook, and XITS/XITS Math are installed (I can see them in Font Book).

I've already removed all use of mathtools from my slides, but any thoughts on what's happening? Presumably I'm just doing something wrong.

Comment: There is https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303538/xelatex-mathtools-unicode-math-and-text-spoil-mathtt but I guess its old, as the bug was apparently fixed in Tex Live 2016?

Comment: Shouldn't unicode-math always be loaded last?

Comment: @daleif thanks for the comment. yes, that is the recommendation which I did also try; it doesn't help. But that is  likely "less wrong" so I will edit the order.

Comment: If you're on tl17 you should really update

Comment: @daleif :) Also a fair point...I'll get to it probably on tuesday (after this thing is due)

Comment: I cannot duplicate this bug on either LuaLaTex or XeLaTeX in TeX Live 2021.

Comment: You might see if `\setoperatorfont{\mathrm}` fixes it, or `\setmathrm{XITS}`.

Comment: those didn't work. But I can confirm that updating to Tex Live 2021 did! Thanks everyone

Comment: I can reproduce this bug with TeXLive 2017 (on Overleaf), but newer versions of TeX Live should have this bug fixed. Also, I vote to close this questions since it can be solved by updating.

Comment: @JasperHabicht thank you for the close vote. I now know that we close for such a reason on tex.SE. If the question should be deleted it seems I have a button for that